# Custom Object Tab is not visible in "Show All Tab" when created via Apex

Tags: apex, metadata-api

We have a VF page which creates Object, fields, RecordType and assigns them to Profiles and also creates Tab for the object and assigns them to the profiles using the [MetadataAPI wrapper](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi).

Below is the piece of code which created Tab for the custom object:

```
public static void createTab(String sessionId, String objectName) {
    MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService(sessionId);
    List<MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery> queries = new List<MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery>();
    MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery profileMetaData = new MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery();
    profileMetaData.type_x = 'Profile';
    queries.add(profileMetaData);
    MetadataService.FileProperties[] fileProperties = service.listMetadata(queries,38);
    List<MetadataService.Profile> profileList = new List<MetadataService.Profile>();
    Map<Id, Profile> profilesToConsider = new Map<Id, Profile>(
        [
            SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE UserType = 'Standard'
        ]
    );

    for(MetadataService.FileProperties fileProperty : fileProperties){
        MetadataService.Profile profile = new MetadataService.Profile();
        profile.fullName = fileProperty.fullName;

        if(profilesToConsider.containsKey(fileProperty.Id)) {


            List<MetadataService.ProfileRecordTypeVisibility> profileRecordTypeVisibilityList = new List<MetadataService.ProfileRecordTypeVisibility>();

            List<MetadataService.ProfileTabVisibility> profileTabVisibilityList = new List<MetadataService.ProfileTabVisibility>();

            MetadataService.ProfileTabVisibility profileTabVisibility = new MetadataService.ProfileTabVisibility();
            profileTabVisibility.tab = objectName;
            profileTabVisibility.visibility = 'DefaultOn';

            profileTabVisibilityList.add(profileTabVisibility);
            profile.tabVisibilities = profileTabVisibilityList;

            profileRecordTypeVisibilityList.add(profileRecordTypeVisibility);
            profile.recordTypeVisibilities = profileRecordTypeVisibilityList;

            profileList.add(profile);

            List<MetadataService.UpsertResult> results = service.upsertMetadata(profileList);

        }
    }

}
```

Everything seems to work fine except the fact that Tab which got created is not visible in the "All tabs" even though the Tab is marked as "Default On" in the profile detail page.

> So I opened the System Admin profile, clicked the "Edit" button and
>   clicked "Save" without changing anything. Now the Tab shows up in the
>   "All Tabs" page.

Not sure what is happening here? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the exact same situation. I also tested redeploying the same Profile update with 'DefaultOn' after a minute to more simulate a manual touch update, but still doesn't show up in All Tabs (and not searchable via Global Search). The only solution to make the tab truly visible is still to manually click Edit and Save with no changes.